# SQL SUM on DISTINCT values per time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum, distinct

I have the following table. First column is the Object Id, then the object size and finally the time that the specific object is sold.

```
Object  Price           Moment
   A    100     2014-10-10 22:12:00
   B    105     2014-10-10 22:12:44
   A    100     2014-10-10 22:14:12
   C    203     2014-10-10 22:15:02
   B    105     2014-10-10 22:17:34
   D    68      2014-10-10 22:42:01
   C    203     2014-10-10 22:43:02
```

By using the following sql, I get the Sum of price of all objects, that are sold every 15 minutes.

```
SELECT
Date(Moment)  Date,
sec_to_time(time_to_sec(Moment) - time_to_sec(Moment)%(15*60)) 15MinInterval,
Sum(Price) PriceSum
FROM table
GROUP BY
    Date,
    15MinInterval
ORDER BY
    Date,
    15MinInterval
```

This works well, and the results that I get are:

```
2014-10-10 22:00:00 305
2014-10-10 22:15:00 308
2014-10-10 22:30:00 271
```

What I need, and I can not find a way to do it, is to calculate the Sum of price of all DISTINCT objects, every 15 minutes. So, for the specific table, I need to get the following results:

```
2014-10-10 22:00:00 205
2014-10-10 22:15:00 308
2014-10-10 22:30:00 271
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT` in a sub query

**SQL Fiddle** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc040/9

```
SELECT
Date,
15Interval 15MinInterval,
Sum(Price) PriceSum
FROM
(SELECT  DISTINCT
OBJECT,
Price,
Date(Moment)  Date,
sec_to_time(time_to_sec(Moment) - time_to_sec(Moment)%(15*60)) AS 15Interval
FROM mytable) temp
GROUP BY
    Date,
    15MinInterval
ORDER BY
    Date,
    15MinInterval
```

OUTPUT

[image]